# Error message about GTK in terminal

Tags: 12.04, gtk, icon-themes

When i write some command on terminal, this error message appear

```
FirstStrike@ubuntu:~$ gksu

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:6934): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
```

I have no idea about this, can anyone tell me if this a serious problem ?

Comment: have you recently upgraded anything? usually this happens after an upgrade for example Ubuntu release upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 stuff like themes that you used on 13.10 for example require more libs and so on with 14.04 version

Comment: @JohnnyD. Yea, before i ask this to askubuntu. I also try `sudo apt-get dist upgrade`

Comment: if you did release upgrade even `apt-get dist-upgrade` won't help you that much it's nothing serious but consider reinstalling troubleshooting stuff that you have for example I was using GTK theme Delorean on 12.04 after upgrade to 14.04 I got a whole bunch of GTK warnings so just removed it and found appropriate Delorean theme ppa for Trusty Tahr and poof warnings disappeared :) good luck.